# No success executing foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wrote a following PHP+codeigniter code:

```
$msg = $this->db->get('Messages');
$curDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$array = array('IsRead =' => 0, 'Date <=' => $curDate);

$this->db->where($array);
$this->db->set(array('IsRead' => 1));
$this->db->update('Messages');
```

Which basically checks which records in Messages table meet the two conditions regarding fields `IsRead` and `Date`, and then updates only those records.

Now I would like to pick up every `Date` value that meets said criteria and execute some PHP code for it. I suppose it's a job that foreach directive could manage, but I have no success coding it.

Could I ask for some help.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, hope  will  help....

```
    $curDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $array = array('IsRead' => 0, 'Date <=' => $curDate);
    $this->db->where($array);
    $this->db->set('IsRead',1));
    $this->db->update('Messages');
    if ($this->db->affected_rows()>0) {
      echo "Update successful";       
       }
      else
      {
        echo "No any row updated";
      }
```

Comment: Thank you, may I just clarify. The intention is to gather all of the changed rows, and then execute a PHP loop that will take each of the Date values one-by-one, and send them as parameters to another function within a PHP file.

Comment: did you get your result?

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer seems to be:

```
    $curDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $array = array('IsRead =' => 0, 'Date<=' => $curDate);

    $this->db->where($array);
    $msg = $this->db->get('Messages');
    foreach ($msg->result() as $row)
    {
            echo $row->Date . " "; //here goes the PHP code
    }

    $this->db->where($array);
    $this->db->set(array('IsRead' => 1));
    $this->db->update('Messages');
```